# How to make polymorphic async hasMany relationships with ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am in the process of porting ember-data .13 to the latest ember-data and can't get polymorphic hasMany-relationships to work correctly.

I have a model Person. A person has many posts. The posts are polymorphic, so there are photoPosts, textPosts, ...

The posts should be loaded in an async request, but the only way to get polymorphism to work is by sideloading the tasks. (http://jsfiddle.net/koenig/3qwEP/7/)

Here are my models

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    person: DS.belongsTo('person') 
});

App.PhotoPost = App.Post.extend({
    photoUrl: DS.attr('string'),
    postType: 'photo' 
});

App.TextPost = App.Post.extend({
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    postType: 'text'
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true, polymorphic: true}),

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

This is my payload for persons:

```
person: {
    id: 1, 
    first_name: 'luke', 
    last_name: 'skywalker', 
    links: { posts: '/people/1/posts' }
}
```

This for posts:

```
posts: [ 
    {id: 1, title: 'A Photo', type: "photoPost" }, 
    {id: 2, title: 'Some Text', type: "textPost" }
]
```

I also tried different payloads and variations, played around with various serializer hooks and looked for the answer in ember-data code. No luck yet.

Am I missing something or are async polymorphic relationships not possible in ember data?

Here is a jsfiddle with the basic setup: http://jsfiddle.net/koenig/3qwEP/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I've been working on an Ancestry/Self-Join relationship example right now. https://github.com/brandonjmckay/ember-ancestry-example I haven't seen the `polymorphic: true` method before, so I'm not sure if that's legacy.

Comment: BTW The example works great in Fixtures, or with loading all the records in the index. But my next step is getting proper async or model reloading when dirty going.

Comment: Also, there is now an http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ Which does a quick mock ember setup for you. Saves some work.

Comment: I found the polymorphic setting for `hasMany` at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ManyArray.html#property_isPolymorphic is it not meant to be set to `isPolymorphic` `true/false` ?